# DataGrid looses focus but SelectedItem is not set to null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus, selecteditem

I have a DataGrid in WPF. I have binded SelectedItem property. I have Remove button which removes selected row. However when I click to other place (i.e. TextBox) and DataGrid has lost a focus, SelectedItem does not change. I can Remove the row, that was selected "earlier".

Is it default behaviour you would expected? Can it be easily fixed?

edit (code as requested):

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPort}" (...) >

<Button Command="{Binding RemovePortCommand}" >Remove Port</Button>

public ICommand RemovePortCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _removePortCommand ?? (_removePortCommand = new RelayCommand(param => OnRemovePortCommand(), param => SelectedPort != null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the delete and the binding.

Answer (score 2):

That's Good man....

just use your Binding property to set

```
grid.SelectedItem =null;
```

OR

```
grid.selectedindex = -1
```

Or both, after delete

Comment: After deleting it's set to null. Works fine. But after loosing focus (clicking somewhere else) it is not set to null.

Comment: No, because you set SelectedItem, You need to tell grid that nothing now selected...Does that make sense......yes, Losing focus does not deselect....

Comment: My comment was missleading. What I ment: Currently after deleting a row, it is set to null by a framework. Works fine. Setting it explicity as you proposed does not help here.

Comment: When you lose focus, You would not expect SelectedItem to be null implicitely, Its remain selected, Think of master details View(where you can edit details), What should happens if you lose focus?